# Is there any linux utility to create plain binary dump of file and vice versa?

Tags: conversion, hex

I want to know is there any linux utility or procedure for generating plain binary dump and reversing it back to the original file (as `xxd` is capable of doing it with `-r` argument)? I have tried `xxd`, it have the option to reverse to original file  but it only prints plain hex dumps.

In case if above is not possible, is there any utility for conversion of plain hex strings (Example : `hx829jdxkdiei`) into plain binary. On windows there are some programs like 010 Editor, but I am not able to find any for Command line linux.

Comment: `generating plain binary dump and reversing it back` ... back to what? ... it is unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: @jsotola As xxd is capable of doing it with -r argument

Comment: `hx829jdxkdiei` can't be hex. Did you mean base64?

Comment: See also [How to obtain a plain (raw) binary dump of any file in Unix/Linux?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/195105)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `perl`:

```
perl -ple 'BEGIN{$/=\8} $_=unpack("B*")' < file > file.dump
```

(`B` for the 0x1 8-bit byte (octet) to be dumped as `00000001`; replace with `b` to get `10000000` instead)

Reverse:

```
perl -pe '$_=pack("B*", $_)' < file.dump > file
```

Example:

```
$ printf %s hx829jdxkdiei | perl -ple 'BEGIN{$/=\8}$_=unpack("B*")'
0110100001111000001110000011001000111001011010100110010001111000
0110101101100100011010010110010101101001
$ printf %s hx829jdxkdiei | perl -ple 'BEGIN{$/=\8}$_=unpack("B*")' |
    perl -pe '$_=pack("B*", $_)'
hx829jdxkdiei
```

For hex dump to binary dump:

```
$ echo ff0aa0ff | perl -ple '$_=unpack("B*", pack("H*",$_))'
11111111000010101010000011111111
$ printf %s hx829jdxkdiei | xxd -p -c8 | perl -ple '$_=unpack("B*", pack("H*",$_))'
0110100001111000001110000011001000111001011010100110010001111000
0110101101100100011010010110010101101001
```

With `zsh`, see also:

```
$ string=hx829jdxkdiei
$ set +o multibyte -o extendedglob
$ bin=${string//(#m)?/${(l[8][0])$(( [##2] ##$MATCH ))}}
$ print -r -- $bin
01101000011110000011100000110010001110010110101001100100011110000110101101100100011010010110010101101001
$ print ${bin//(#m)?(#c8)/${(#):-"2#$MATCH"}}
hx829jdxkdiei
```

Where

- `$(( ##x ))` gives you the value of character `x` (`wchar_t` value with the `multibyte` option on, byte value otherwise).
- `$(( [##2] expression ))` expands the result of the arithmetic expression in binary (without the `2#` prefix).
- `${(l[8][0])param}` `l`eft pads the parameter expansion to length 8 with 0s.
- `${(#)param}` outputs the character whose value is stored in `$param` (reverse of `$(( ##x ))`).

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to dump to hex, I would use `hexdump`, or `xxd`.

However, you mentioned 010 Editor, which is a hex *editor*. There are plenty of hex editors for Linux. For example, see [this part of the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/List_of_applications#Hex_editors), or [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors).